# How to sort the list of files name and write them in a JSON using php?

Tags: php, json

I write code for getting list of files from server and write them in a JSON file but here an issue every time it will changed automatically. 
my code is

```
<?php
$dir = "office/";
if(is_dir($dir)){
    if($dh = opendir($dir)){
        while(($file = readdir($dh)) != false){
            if($file != "." and $file != ".."){
                $files_array[] = array('file' => $file); // Add the file to the array
            } 
        }
    }
    $return_array =array('dir' => $files_array);
    exit (json_encode($return_array));
}
?>
```

and output is

```
{
    "dir": [
        {
            "file": "FreeWallApp.zip"
        },{
            "file": "20151211_Clip.7z"
        },{
            "file": "QRite.7z"
        },{
            "file": "CustomDialog_app.zip"
        },{
            "file": "LockScreenBasicApp.apk"
        },{
            "file": "ImgViewEffects.zip"
        },{
            "file": "98765Img.zip"
        },
      ]
    }
```

Here my question is that **how to sort** that list of such name like first
a b c ..... and then 1 2 3

```
{
    "dir": [
        {
            "file": "CustomDialog_app.zip"
        },{
            "file": "FreeWallApp.zip"
        },{
            "file": "LockScreenBasicApp.apk"
        },{
            "file": "QRite.7z"
        },{
            "file": "20151211_Clip.7z"
        },{
            "file": "98765Img.zip"
        },
      ]
    }
```

I need above output which is sorted i.e. `CustomDialog_app.zip`, `FreeWallApp.zip`..... then `20151211_Clip.7z`, `98765Img.zip`...

Comment: it's better if you sort it in php and then make it json....

Comment: Any way i use these methods its work for me. :)
[PHP:Sorting](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Comment: exactly that's what i want to say.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added only one line `sort($files_array);` Its works fine...

```
<?php 
$dir = ".";
if(is_dir($dir)){
    if($dh = opendir($dir)){
        while(($file = readdir($dh)) != false){
            if($file != "." and $file != ".." and $file!="index.php"){
                $files_array[] = array('file' => $file); // Add the file to the array
            } 
        }
     // this line make my problem solved
        sort($files_array);
    }
    $return_array =array('dir' => $files_array);
    exit (json_encode($return_array));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First use `"sort"` to sort natural shorting of array. then use below custom code:

```
$abcd[0]["file"] = "FreeWallApp.zip";
$abcd[1]["file"] = "CustomDialog_app.zip";
$abcd[2]["file"] = "20151211_Clip.7z";
$abcd[3]["file"] = "QRite.7z";
$abcd[4]["file"] = "LockScreenBasicApp.apk";
$abcd[5]["file"] = "ImgViewEffects.zip";
$abcd[6]["file"] = "98765Img.zip";

sort($abcd);

 $array1 = array();
 $array2 = array();
 foreach($abcd as $bb){

if(is_numeric(substr(array_values(explode(".",$bb['file']))[0] , 0,1 ) ))  {

    $array1[]["file"] = $bb['file'] ;
}else{

    $array2[]["file"] = $bb['file'] ;
} 

}
$abcd = array_merge ($array2,$array1)  ;

echo json_encode($abcd);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this:

https://linqjs.codeplex.com/

If you are .net developer, it's great library.

Hope this help.